# Coding standards for Angular2/TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I'm wondering if there's at least some community consensus on how to write reusable Angular2 code in TypeScript. I tried to summarise what I found out and what I'd like to know in context of Angular2.

#### Module/App directory structure and file names

- In the [official tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) I see they put all code into `app` directory and all dependencies like `node_modules` or typings are in the parent directory.
- Lowercase file names, `.component.ts` suffix for components and `.service.ts` for services. They put all files to the same directory which is going to be a huge mess?
- One class/interface/enum per file. For classes, functions, interfaces and other names its probably best to stick to [Coding guidelines for TypeScript by Microsoft](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Coding-guidelines)?

#### Modules

- Should modules compile and bundle themselves using `postinstall` `npm` hook? Or is it better to provide bundled version directly on git like most JavaScript libraries do?
- Should I stick to `system` type of modules by default when I'm expecting that my module's going to be used only by browser or is it better to always use [UMD](https://github.com/umdjs/umd)?
- Is there any reason to use [CommonJS](http://requirejs.org/docs/commonjs.html) or [AMD](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html) instead of `system`?

#### Using 3rd party modules

- Should I expect that other developers will embed my modules with `<script>` tags or they'll load it using `System.import()`?
- If my modules has dependencies on other JavaScript libraries, is it better to provide a bundled version of my whole module with all dependencies or just define them in `package.json`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's the *Angular 2 Style Guide* (https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-style-guide), as featured in [Angular2 News](https://angular.io/news.html):

> The purpose of the following style guide is to present a set of best practices and style guidelines for the development of Angular 2 applications. If you are looking for an opinionated style guide for syntax, conventions...

Answer (score 1):

Angular 1 had a community accepted style guide written by John Papa. There will be something similar created for Angular 2 in fact you can see the start of this coming together with the Tour of Heroes examples in place at [angular.io](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/)